# Python constantly deleting lines after saving one

Tags: python, python-2.7, sorting, line, strip

My code looks like

```html
from __future__ import print_function
import linecache
from random import choice
from string import digits, ascii_lowercase
import random, string
import fileinput
 

 
L = ''.join([random.choice(string.ascii_letters + string.digits) for n in xrange(10)])
print(L)
 
 
 
 

with open("input.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        ok = (line)
        ok = line.strip()
        if line > 6:
            f = open('output.txt', 'a' )
            f.write( str(ok) +" " + str(L) + '\n')
            f.close()
            total_count = 0 
            for line in fileinput.input('output.txt', inplace=True):
                count = line.count(ok)
                if count > 0:
                    print(line, end='')
                    total_count += count
            print (total_count)
```

My input file is:

```
55
99
42
65
49
49
```

My problem here is that it's supposed to be saving all of the numbers but instead it's only saving the last 2, any help would be appreciated

Comment: You should be getting an error at `if line > 6:` because you're comparing a string (your first input would look like '55') to an integer (6).

Comment: you are overriding `f` at `f = open('output.txt', 'a' )`

Comment: it's not giving me an error and i changed f to ff and im getting the same result

Comment: seems the last loop in the code: `for line in fileinput.input('output.txt', inplace=True):` may be causing the problem. try moving the indentation of that entire block (from `for line in fileinput.input ...` to the end `print (total_count)`) back to the left margin (align with line `with open("input.txt") as f:`), and run the script again.

Comment: @davedwards it's now successfully saving lines but only the last two and every time i run it it just keeps on adding those two which are "49"

Comment: any help would be appreciated

Comment: @OPP, what should the contents of "output.txt" contain? all values from the "input.txt" that are greater than `6` with a second column of the random string `L`?

Comment: @davedwards correct

Comment: ok cool, I think the `fileinput` module may be causing problems getting the correct output. What is the line `count = line.count(ok)` counting?

Comment: I changed the code a lot here, take a look at this, see if it does what you want it to do: https://repl.it/@downshift/LividThornyLangur

Comment: Yes it's supposed to count how many times a line in the input file appears in the output file  @davedwards

Comment: ok, we can get that by just counting how many lines are in `output.txt`, or incrementing the `count` variable like you are already doing. Is there a reason you are checking if a number in the input file is greater than `6`? Because 6 is also the number of lines in the input file. Is there a relation to why you're checking if `if int(line) > 6:`, or is that not related ?

Comment: there's no relationship, what im trying to do here is take each line in the input file, check if it's greater than a certain number and if  it is check how many times it appears in my output file, then proceed to save it

Comment: Ok cool, thanks for confirming that. Check the output at that link again (https://repl.it/@downshift/LividThornyLangur) and see if it works. Or I can post it as an answer if you prefer.

Comment: @davedwards the code you're referring to is constantly deleting the contents of the output file and seems to only be counting how many lines there are, not how many times a line in my input is appearing in the output

Comment: @OPP, sorry, I thought that's what your requirements actually were. It's deleting the output file contents before writing the new output (otherwise it would add more different contents to the output file each time you run it). Is the output file empty when you run the script I referred to?

Comment: The count is actually counting *only* when a line in the input file *will be* added to the output file, but we can do that many different ways. To check it, change a value in the input file to something *less than* `6`. You should see the count (and the output file contents) change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems the [fileinput](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fileinput.html) module may be causing issues with correctly writing the file output, but I am not sure how that module works so I cannot suggest how to use it.

The main correction may be to use different file handler pointers for reading the input file and writing to the output file (*don't* reuse `f` as mentioned in the comments).

Here's some refactoring of your original code:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import linecache
from random import choice
from string import digits, ascii_lowercase
import random, string
from collections import defaultdict

L = ''.join([random.choice(string.ascii_letters + string.digits) for n in xrange(10)])
print(L)

total_count = defaultdict(lambda: 0)

with open("input.txt", 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        ok = line.strip()
        if int(line) > 6:
            total_count[int(line)] += 1
            with open('output.txt', 'a' ) as ff:
                ff.write( str(ok) + " " + str(L) + '\n')

infile_contents = []
outfile_contents = []

# get list of input.txt contents
with open('input.txt', 'r') as infile:
    for line in infile.readlines():
        infile_contents.append(line.strip())

# get list of output.txt first column contents
with open('output.txt', 'r') as outfile:
    for line in outfile.readlines():
        outfile_contents.append(line.split()[0])        

# dictionary to hold count of occurrences
totals = {}

# count occurrences
for num in infile_contents:
    totals[num] = outfile_contents.count(num)

# print counts
for item in totals.items():
    print('{num} appears {count} times.'.format(num=item[0], count=item[1]))
```

Example output after running script twice:

```
vlVHVi3t9L
55 appears 2 times.
99 appears 2 times.
42 appears 2 times.
65 appears 2 times.
49 appears 4 times.
```

Comment: this code is constantly deleting the contents of the output file just to save the new lines and seems to only be counting how many lines there are, not how many times a line in my input is appearing in the output an example would be 42 appearing two times in output.txt

Comment: `42` should only appear *once* in the output.txt file (see example output in answer above, only one `42` entry). Do you mean `49` appearing twice should only be counted `once`?

Comment: The problem here is it's deleting all of the contents of the output file when it should be saving after lets say i run the code 3 times, 42 should appear in the output file 3 times, which should be printed in the python shell

Comment: Ah interesting, ok I removed the line that deletes the output.txt contents. I'll try to fix it to also count the occurrences file contents.

Comment: Please the new code in the answer and provide feedback if it's not helpful. thanks

Comment: it working ok but it's not counting properly, it seems to only count the amount of lines, not how many times each line in the input appears in the output

Comment: lets say i ran the code twice so now there's two of each number in my output  it should say 42 came up 2 times in the file, 65 came up 2 times in the file, 49 came up 2 times in the file etc.

Comment: Ok, that's a really big change of requirement that you should have mentioned in the original question. I've updated with code that does that. Note the `49` appears `4` times since it occurs twice in the original `input.txt` file.

Comment: one more thing, is it possible to check if the line in the input appears in the output file only if it's greater than 6, basically to put the rest of the code under if int(line) > 6:

Comment: sure, we can do anything you want to do....but where would we check that? the only way a line in the input file will appear in the output file is *only* if the number in the line **is** greater than 6... isn't that what `int(line) > 6:` is doing? Also, what do you mean by "Put the rest of the code under `if int(line) > 6:`? Do you want to indent all the lines of code to be under the line `if int(line) > 6:` Just for code stucture?

Comment: What I basically want the code to do is go though the input line by line, and when it encounters a number greater than 6 only then it should check how many of it there is in the output file (right after saving it),i dont want it to blindly check every line in the input on a separate code. what im saying here is i want it to check how many of it there is ONLY if it it's greater than 6. that's why i wanted it under if int(line) > 6:

Comment: Ok, I think I understand, so you want to perform the counting of each number occurrence inside the logic that checks if the number is greater than `6`? Instead of doing the counting later in the code?

Comment: yes, only do the counting only if the number is greater than 6

Comment: the output is still the same thing

Comment: What should the output change to be? I thought you only wanted to change the code logic, not the output. Maybe provide what your expected output should look like.

Comment: Thank you. How is the output different from that? What part not being output? With the same input, the *output* should not change..

Comment: the code you provided doesn't follow the logic that checks if the number is greater than 6

Comment: how is the logic different? it's simple one line `if int(line) > 6:` the same we've discussed earlier. How should that logic change?

Comment: You do mean "If the **value** in each line is greater than `6`", right?

Comment: That's when it should actually check to see if the line is in the output and count how many times it appears

Comment: ok, so there's nothing wrong with the output, but you want all the checking if the line is in the output and count to occur ***within*** the `with open("input.txt", 'r') as f:` loop, and not at the end of the code, as I currently have done. is that correct?

Comment: Doing that may require reading and writing to the output file at the same time, sorry I don't know if that's even possible.